# How to include a range in C++ guessing game and get code to repeat?

Tags: c++

A simple guessing game, but I need instead of simply telling the user that their guess was too high or too low, modify the code such that the user is now given a range of numbers within which the chosen number actually lies.

Precisely,the user is shown a range [*low*, *high*] such that *low* ≤ *num* ≤ *high*.
At the beginning of the game, [*low*, *high*] = [*0*, *100*], but as the user makes more guesses, the range is refined and a more accurate range is shown.

**An example:**
Suppose that *num* = *78*. You first ask the user to make a guess between [*0*, *100*].
The user enters *50* as their guess. So the next range would be [*51*, *100*] since *51* ≤ *78* ≤ *100*.
On the other hand, if the user had entered *90*, then the next range would have been [*0*, *89*].

Can someone also help me figure out how to get user input so that the code can repeat and they can play again?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num, guess, tries = 0;
    srand(time(0)); 
    num = rand() % 100 + 1; 
    cout << "Guess My Number Game\n\n";

    do {
        cout << "Enter a guess between 1 and 100 : ";
        cin >> guess;
        tries++;

        if (guess > num)
            cout << "Too high!\n\n";
        else if (guess < num)
            cout << "Too low!\n\n";
        else
            cout << "\nCorrect! You got it in " << tries << " guesses!\n";
    } while (guess != num);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Please elaborate a little by giving desired input and output

Comment: @kesarlingHe-Him the desired output should be where the program gives a range inside of which the answer lies each time the user inputs a number. at the end when the user gets it correct the program should the ask the user to play again. Am confused about these two steps and what the implementation looks like

Comment: So you mean something like if the answer is 30, and used enters 50, then the program should say the answer is between 25 and 35? Again, edit the question to give an example

Comment: @kesarlingHe-Him I've edited the question, yes exactly like that. How would I then get the user to repeat the program?

Comment: So the range needs to be `[wrong_number_entered(+/-)1, (maximum/minimum) limit]`? What is so tough in this concept?

Comment: @kesarlingHe-Him I'm just not sure what the code would look like for that?

Comment: If you want the program to repeat, you should put the appropriate parts of the program in a loop.

Comment: You need to add two variables to your program in order to keep track of the range of possible values, from the user's perspective. At the start, the possible range will be `0` to `100`, so those should be the values of the two variables. As the user makes guesses, you should adapt the values of these variables.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend you to use rand() and stime since it's a bit old and might give you duplicated numbers, use the modern random library, I do this sometimes to get random number in range:

```
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 mt(rd());
std::uniform_real_distribution<double> dist(1.0, 10.0);
float rnd = dist(mt);
unsigned int flt = rnd;
```

you might want to add inside your code a new random number generation each time user gives input and just replace  `std::uniform_real_distribution<double> dist(1.0, 10.0);` with new range you need 2 random if I understood what you want properly